# Do I have to wear the specific Amiibo gear in order to get the rest of the gears?

Tags: splatoon-3

I want to get new gears and soon from Amiibos but I'm not sure if you need to wear the first gear item you get from the Amiibo (shoes) in order to get the other gear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to wear it, you only need to play more Turf Wars, then check back the Amiibo and you'll get another piece of gear.

Comment: Why answer and also vote as a duplicate of your own post?

Comment: @TimmyJim because I vtc but I wasn't sure if I was right, OP is asking a similar question but with a detail not specified in the other answer. If it's not needed I'll delete this.